# Dbset is not getting the data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

```
class InvoiceAppDBContext: DbContext
    {
        public InvoiceAppDBContext() : base("InvoiceDBContext")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Users> User { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; } 
    }




class DataBaseUserRespository : IUser
    {
        private InvoiceAppDBContext _dbContext;

        public DataBaseUserRespository()
        {
            _dbContext = new InvoiceAppDBContext();
        }
        public IEnumerable<Users> _userList
        {
            get
            {
                return _dbContext.User; // this is not working _userlist is showing null when i run it 
            }
        }

        public void SaveUser(Users user)
        {
            if(user.UserId == 0)
            {
                _dbContext.User.Add(user);
            }
            else
            {
                Users userEntity = _dbContext.User.Find(user.UserId);
                userEntity.Change(user);
            }
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

so `DBSet` or `DBcontext` is not getting the data from the table and putting it in `IEnumerable<Users>` list.

[here i am debugging the userlist(accountList) and it is not showing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFkQT.png)

hopefully this explains what problem i am getting :)

Comment: No it does not explain what problems do you have. As you are filtering the data may be you dont have matching record. Try doing `.ToList()` in watch window on `accountList` and see if that has any records.

Comment: the reason i put the image to show the data inside the accountList (which is a IEnumerable) when i debug. ignore the other code. the problem is that Dbset or DBcontext is not getting the data from table to accountList

Comment: @Mirza can you please place debug point at constructor DataBaseUserRespository() and check InvoiceAppDBContext connectionstring... Hope it is not the case that it is pointing sqlLocalDb and you are expecting it to get data from different server

Comment: Lets start with the basics... `_dbContext.Database.Exists()` is returning `true`? You checked with some other tool, that some data are actually in the database? When debugging `AccountList`, you expanded the entry and expanded the enumerable in order to inspect the results?